# Any efficient way to avoiding two forloops in django

Tags: django, django-templates

Any better or efficient way to this in django

```
{% for list1item in list1 %}
   {% for list2item in list2 %}
      {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
          {{ list1item }} {{ list2item }}
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to do something like this, but not working.

```
{% for list1item in list1 %}
   {% with forloop.counter as i %}
      {{ list2.i }}
   {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Updated! Actually here is the story!**
this is my **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import MedicalRecords

class UpdateMedicalRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MedicalRecords
        fields = ("title", "file", "doctor")

        widgets = {
            "title": forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows": "", "class": "form-control"}),
        }
```

I want a list of each medicalrecord form with It's instance so I'm using `[UpdateMedicalRecordForm(instance=x) for x in medicalrecords]` to create form for each medicalrecord.
my **view.py** is as

```
...
medicalrecords = get_list_or_404(MedicalRecords,somefilterings..)
forms = [UpdateMedicalRecordForm(instance=x) for x in medicalrecords]
...
```

then in **template** to access each form of medical record I'm using

```
<form method="POST" enctype="" class="">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for form in forms reversed %}
              {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <div class="submit-section text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary submit-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Have you consider doing this logic in your view and then passing in the context only the values you are interested in ?

Comment: would you display the result (what you need to achieve), so it would be easy to say.

Comment: hey guys thanks for replays, I updated and explained what I'm really doing. :)

Comment: @AliAref why not simply use `form.instance` to get the instance of the model? No need for all of this looping / indexing.

Comment: there are many medical record so I'm getting the **instances** by ```[UpdateMedicalRecordForm(instance=x) for x in medicalrecords]``` and store them in **forms** then loop through forms.. so that i can edit each on template.. I have all the instance of medicalrecords in a single table..
I'm new to django so not really sure how to do.

Comment: @AliAref when a form is instantiated with the model instance you can access the model instance via `form.instance` so instead of looping over the records you can directly loop over the forms and access any model attributes via `form.instance.attribute`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can [create a custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) in order to make your solution working :

```
# templatetags/custom_tags.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_index(obj, index):
    """
    Try to get value from a list object with an index given in parameter.
    Return an empty string if index doesn't exist
    """
    try:
        return obj[index]
    except IndexError:
        return ""
```

Then in your template you can do :

```
{% load custom_tags %}

{% for list1item in list1 %}
    {{ list2|get_index:forloop.counter }}
{% endfor %}
```

But after reading your update, I believe you can find something cleaner for your use case.